# cloud functions returning null for dataSnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am using cloud notifications for sending notifications whenever some data is updated in the realtime database, and I am sending the notificaations with some details which are also from the database
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.notifyUsers = functions.database.ref('/').onUpdate(event => {
  var message = event.data.val();
  admin.database().ref('users/'+message.uid).on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
    var usernameOfSender = dataSnapshot.child('username').val();
    console.log('message: '+message.val());
    console.log('dataSnapshot.val: '+dataSnapshot.val());
    console.log('usernameOfSender: '+usernameOfSender);
    // Notification details.
    const text = message.message;
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: `${usernameOfSender} posted ${text ? 'a message' : 'an image'}`,
        body: text ? (text.length <= 100 ? text : text.substring(0, 97) + '...') : '',
        icon: dataSnapshot.child('profilePic').val() || '/images/defaultProfilePic.png',
        click_action: `https://${functions.config().firebase.authDomain}`
      }
    };
    // Get the list of device tokens.
    return admin.database().ref('fcmTokens').once('value').then(allTokens => {
      if (allTokens.val()) {
        // Listing all tokens.
        const tokens = Object.keys(allTokens.val());

        // Send notifications to all tokens.
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
          // For each message check if there was an error.
          const tokensToRemove = [];
          response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
            const error = result.error;
            if (error) {
              console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
              // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
              if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                  error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                tokensToRemove.push(allTokens.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
              }
            }
          });
          return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

When I check my firebase console, this is what I get:

```
usernameOfSender: null
dataSnapshot.val: null
message: [object Object]
```

and the notification comes as null posted an image, with the default profile picture.

Comment: Can you do a JSON.stringify(message), so we do not get [object Object]

Also this is wrong  console.log('message: '+message.val());, as you already did  var message = event.data.val();

Comment: @Ian Oh wait `JSON.stringify(message) works! Wow! Now I just have the dataSnapshot problem...